# Convert numeric types: Which style to use?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Let's say I want to convert a Double `x` to a Decimal `y`. There's a *lot* of ways to do that:

```
1. var y = Convert.ToDecimal(x);    // Dim y = Convert.ToDecimal(x)
2. var y = new Decimal(x);          // Dim y = new Decimal(x)
3. var y = (decimal)x;              // Dim y = CType(x, Decimal)
4. -- no C# equivalent --           // Dim y = CDec(x)
```

Functionally, all of the above do the same thing (as far as I can tell). Other than personal taste and style, is there a particular reason to choose one option over the other?

**EDIT**: This is the IL generated by compiling the three C# options in a Release configuration:

```
1. call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Convert::ToDecimal(float64)
   --> which calls System.Decimal::op_Explicit(float64)
       --> which calls System.Decimal::.ctor(float64)
2. newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(float64)
3. call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Decimal::op_Explicit(float64)
   --> which calls System.Decimal::.ctor(float64)
```

This is the IL generated by compiling the four VB options in a Release configuration:

```
1. call valuetype [mscorlib]System.Decimal [mscorlib]System.Convert::ToDecimal(float64)
   --> which calls System.Decimal::op_Explicit(float64)
       --> which calls System.Decimal::.ctor(float64)
2. call instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(float64)  
3. newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(float64)
4. newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Decimal::.ctor(float64)
```

So, it all ends up in `System.Decimal::.ctor(float64)`

Comment: Did you happen to check which IL code is generated?

Comment: You need to change CType to DirectCast to be equivalent.

Comment: @AMissico: No, DirectCast does not perform conversions. With DirectCast, it won't even compile if x is statically typed to Double.

Comment: You need to add `Convert.ChangeType`.

Comment: @GertArnold: I've added the IL

Comment: @Heinzi; Interesting, I must be doing C# too much. I forgot my roots. :O)

Comment: @AMissico: For the moment, I'd like to stick with the options where the result type is known to the compiler (thus, no `Convert.ChangeType`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Convert.ToInt32()` applies rounding to real numbers while casting to int just removes the fractional part. In my opinion typecasting method for "conversions" relies on .NET framework's magic too much. If you *know* that a conversion will have to take place, describing it explicitly is the easiest to understand. I would go for `Convert` option for most of the cases unless there is no conversion needed and a cast just works.

Answer (score 6):

I would suspect that using the unary casting operator would give the compiler a better chance to optimize, but I base this on absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 1):

With non-object and non-string source data types, I prefer casts. Concise and easy to read.

For object and string source types, it depends on the source. For example, if the source is from the user, then I use Convert/Conversion methods.

I recommend downloading the source code for .NET at "Microsoft Reference Source Code Center" (http://referencesource.microsoft.com). Check out Convert.cs, Converstion.vb, and Conversions.vb. I previously would use the Convert/Conversion methods in all cases, but after reviewing these source files, my preference is casts.

Taking your example `Convert.ToDecimal()` and referencing Convert.cs, the call is really a simple cast:

```
    public static decimal ToDecimal(double value) { 
        return (decimal)value;
    }
```